# Facebook PHP SDK doesn't work through AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

The situation: I have a finished Facebook canvas app (PHP/CodeIgniter), I just need to add the Facebook-related options such as sharing and inviting friends.

Current task: getting the list of invitable friends from the PHP SDK.

Relevant documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0

The code: in my Facebook library, I have created the following function.

```
/**
    * Returns the current user's invitable friends
    */
    public function get_invitable_friends() {
        if ( $this->session ) {
            $request = ( new FacebookRequest( $this->session, 'GET', '/me/invitable_friends' ) )->execute();

            $graphObject = $request->getGraphObject();

            return $graphObject;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The condition `if($this->session)` is because it doesn't make sense to try anything if there's no Facebook session in the first place. This will come into play later.

I've tried calling this function in two ways. The first way works and the second doesn't. I'm gonna present both, and then somebody will hopefully explain to me why the second way doesn't work and how to fix it, as I'd much prefer to use that.

First (working) way:

Call the function from the `main` controller's `index()` method, as the page loads. The function correctly returns a list of my friends.

Second (non-working) way:

Create this function in the controller:

```
//load list of friends we can invite to play the game
    public function load_invitable_friends()
    {
        $this->load->library('facebook');

        $list = $this->facebook->get_invitable_friends();

        var_dump($list);
    }
```

Then call it through AJAX, like:

```
function loadInvites(){
    $.post(base+"main/load_invitable_friends/",function(resp){
        $('#slide_6_inner').html(resp);
    });
}
```

After this call, the content of the `slide_6_inner` div should contain the list of friends, as dumped by `var_dump`. However, the content is `bool(false)`, indicating that the Facebook session is no longer present.

If I remove the condition `if( $this->session )` from the `get_invitable_friends()` method, then this error happens:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, null given, called in /home/lights/public_html/appname/application/libraries/facebook/Facebook.php on line 125 and defined

Filename: Facebook/FacebookRequest.php

Line Number: 182
```

The session in `Facebook.php` is initially created with the following code.

```
$this->ci =& get_instance();
        // Initialize the SDK
        FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $api_id, $api_secret) );

        $this->helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
        $this->session = $this->helper->getSession();
```

To sum up - why is this problem occurring and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why not just use the Javascript API?

Comment: First of all, I have all my other Facebook-related logic in the back-end and I'd like to keep it that way. Also, it's important to figure out why this doesn't work for other reasons which are beyond the scope of this question and I'd rather not digress here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve the session from the server side, you will need to first create a session using the `FacebookCanvasLoginHelper`. This class takes a signed request from Facebook supplied in a POST request, and exchanges it for a `FacebookSession` object. This should only really be done one when a user logs into your application:

```
$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
  $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues  
}
if ($session) {
  // Store this in your PHP session somewhere:
  $token = $session->getToken();
}
```

Thereafter, you should use the token to initialize the session:

```
$token = //GET THIS FROM SESSION
use Facebook\FacebookSession;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app-id', 'app-secret');

// If you already have a valid access token:
$session = new FacebookSession($token);

// To validate the session:
try {
  $session->validate();
} catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // Session not valid, Graph API returned an exception with the reason.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
  // Graph API returned info, but it may mismatch the current app or have expired.
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: But the session was created on the server side in the first place. I don't understand why I would have to use the Javascript login helper. The way I see it: 1) the session exists on the server; 2) when I send an AJAX request from the client to the server, the server should still have the session and be able to deliver data to the client; What am I missing?

Comment: how are you persisting the session you create in the first place? The FacebookCanvasLoginHelper relies on a POST request from FB with the data required to create a session. However it doesn't handle persisting that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I was out. How can I persist it? Is it good practice to just call the CanvasLoginHelper again? Currently I'm just handing over the data to CodeIgniter's session.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems I didn't quite understand how the Facebook session persists (read: doesn't persist) in an application. Answer accepted and bounty awarded.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are not doing anything if session does not exists, just returning false. The problem is occuring because the session is expired/or does not exists, so you have to validate the fbToken and set the session again or create a new one.

You can create a function that checks if user is logged in, like:

```
function CheckFbUser() {

  // Check if existing session exists
  if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) {
  // Create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);

     // Validate token
     try {
          if (!$session->validate()) {
             $session = null;
           }
     } catch (Exception $e) {
       // Catch any exceptions
        $session = null;
     }
  } else {
      // No session
      try {
           $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
      } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
        // handle it for facebook exceptions
      } catch(Exception $e) {
        // handle your php exceptions
      }
   }

   // Check if a session exists
   if ( isset( $session ) ) {

   // Save the session
   $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

   // Create session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
   $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

   // USUALLY, here, people show the Logout Button, or anything alike, but you could it
   // to return true, and then continue to run your code.
 } else {
     // No session

     // USUALLY, here, people show the Login Button, or anything alike, you could
     // use it to return false, or redirect user to login first.
     $helper->getLoginUrl();
  }
}
```

That is just an simple code, to check if user is logged in or not before you run the requests.